# How to use O(log n) mutually independent random bits to generate n pairwise independent random bits

Tags: random, randomized-algorithm

We motivated this problem by “saving space”, yet then, we went ahead and stored n pairwise
independent random bits ξi
. That pretty much defeats the purpose. Show how to use O(log n)
mutually independent random bits to generate n pairwise independent random bits. (Thus, all
you really need to store are those O(log n) bits.)

Comment: A related question on Cross Validated: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/157095/generating-pairwise-independent-bits

Comment: It is different @PeterO.

Comment: Can you explain why your question is different from the one I linked to?